# New flutter project couldn't build on mac os intel chip

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, intel

New Flutter project cant build succefully in Mac mini intel chip
Output :

````
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           17.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart:9:8: Error: Error when reading '../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/vector_math-2.1.4/lib/vector_math_64.dart': Permission denied
../…/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart:9
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
Exited```

`flutter doctor` seems to be fine

I tried delete SDK and create new one but didnt work, i hope someone can help.
````

Comment: please  run `flutter doctor -v` statement in console  and add `screenshot`  from it.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `flutter clean` then `flutter create .` in the root directory. This should reset the plugins. Also, check if there is any outdated plugins in your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade to version 3.3.10.